# How should I associate a ListBox item with an item in a list of mine?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox which has all the names for a list of "Gesture" objects I have.

I want to make it so if I double click on a ListBox item I can then do something with its associated Gesture instance.  What is the best way in C# to associate a ListBox item with an instance of a class of mine?

I'm using WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your question, but typically, the best way to *"associate a `ListBox` item with an instance of a class"* is to simply put the instance itself into the `ListBox`. You only have to take care of what is displayed for the items. If you have a simple scenario, it might be sufficient to just override the class' `ToString()` method. If you need a more sophisticated display, you should consider to create [`DataTemplates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for your classes.

If you do not have access to your Gesture classes, you should *create a wrapper class* for them (something like a *ViewModel*) and do the proposed adjustments for this wrapper class.

Moreover, you should make all those classes *implement a common interface or base class*, so that you can safely cast the currently selected item without adding an `if`-statement for every type that might be in the `ListBox`.

Comment: How do you feel about the ListBoxItem's "Tag" attribute?  Would you suggest against this?

Comment: Well, you could also use that property. However, I never use it except for debugging purposes - *very rarely*. I just do not think that this is a good design. And it might/will make problems later on.
Why not put the instances itself into the ListBox?